# Claim:If $f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$ and if $\lim\limits_{x \to x_{0}}f'(x) $ Does not exist.then $f$ It is not differentiable at $x_0$.

Tags: limits, derivatives

> **Theorem:** If **$f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$**, and if $\lim\limits_{x \to x_{0}}f'(x) = L$ exists, then $f$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$, and $f'(x_{0}) = L$

Now:

Can we say that?

> **Claim:** If **$f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$** and if $\lim\limits_{x \to x_{0}}f'(x) $ Does not exist.then $f$ It is not differentiable at $x_0$.

Comment: No. There are various continuous functions which are everywhere differentiable with non-continuous derivative

Answer (score 5):

No. Take
$$
f(x)=\cases{x^2\sin(1/x)&if $x\neq0$\\0&if $x=0$}
$$
Here, $f$ is continuous, and $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)$ doesn't exist, but $f'(0)$ exists and is equal to $0$.